# How to generate an alert if deployment becomes 'Unhealthy' in Azure Machine Learning?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I deployed an Azure Machine Learning model to AKS, and would like to know how to set an alert if the deployment status changes to any value other than 'Healhty'.  I looked at the monitoring metrics in the workspace, but it looks like they are more related to the training process (Model and Run) and Quotas.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Aazure Machine Learning does not provide a way to continuously monitor the health of your webservice and generate alerts.
You can set up this fairly easily using Application Insights(AML Workspace comes with a provisioned Application Insights).
You can monitor the webservice scoring endpoint using [URL ping or web test in App Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability).

Comment: No - this answer, without the link, is a perfectly good answer. The link isn't required for the answer to be useful so this **isn't** a link-only answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24228669)